# Is this "Cooking Your Dog" book photo digitally faked?

Tags: photography, books

From Twitter:

[image: Cooking Your Dog]

> Cooking [sticker] Your Dog
>
> Tasty, healthy and safe recipes

Is the photo in question digitally faked?

The main doubt I have is whether the book, which can easily be modified to have such a rogue title, exists. I'm not skeptical that, given such a book, a bored employee may choose to place a sticker over the word after "Cooking".

Comment: It was obvious :p

Comment: Compare [To Serve Man](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Serve_Man_(The_Twilight_Zone)), [How To Cook For Forty Humans](https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/How_to_Cook_for_Forty_Humans).

Comment: The word "for" is clearly visible in the price tag ("Cooking for Y").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the book is real.

From [Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005K6QFF8):

[image: Original]

> Cooking **For** Your Dog
>
> Tasty, healthy and safe recipes

In addition, there's another photo ([example link](http://learningfromdogs.com/2011/10/01/cooking-your-dog/)) of the book with a sticker on it, seemingly with a different background:

[image]

Comment: The ISBN-10 number is 1405495146 http://lookupbyisbn.com/Search/Book/1405495146/1

Comment: What do you mean by "different background"? The covers are identical, apart from a slight difference in colour balance due to the different cameras. And the background of the second photo has nothing to do with the book itself.

Comment: @TonyK: different things *behind* the book. What makes it, supposedly and probably, a *different* photo, not the same one, or not even the same actual copy of the book.

Comment: @TonyK the sticker placement is slightly different between the image in this post and the image in the OPs post, so it doesnt look to be the same copy.